# CSS3 Responsive Menu Dropdown on mobile (iPhone) disappears on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, responsive

I'm testing a version of the CSS3 Responsive Menu Dropdown + Submenu width Logo pen by emre on debrioconsulting.com. Everything works fine, for the most part, when viewing in desktop browsers (Mac only so far). But when I test it on my iPhone (6 Plus running iOS 10.3.1) with the dropdown menu open, I go to scroll and the open menu disappears.

Again site is debrioconsulting.com

Here is the css I'm using:

```
/*----------------nav styles---------------------*/

nav {
  position: relative;
  width: 980px;
  /*margin: 0 auto;*/
    margin-top: -60px;
}

#cssmenu {
    font: normal 14px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#cssmenu, #cssmenu ul, #cssmenu ul li, #cssmenu ul li a, #cssmenu #head-mobile {
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box
}

#cssmenu:after, #cssmenu>ul:after {
  content: ".";
  display: block;
  clear: both;
  visibility: hidden;
  line-height: 0;
  height: 0;
}

#cssmenu #head-mobile {
  display: none;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li {
  float: left;
    border-right: 1px solid #FFF;
}

#cssmenu ul li.last {
    border-right: 0;
    }

#cssmenu>ul>li>a {
    padding: 0 29px 0 29px;
  font-size: 14px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FBFCE8;
}

#cssmenu>ul>li:hover>a, #cssmenu ul li.active a {
  color: #E6FF71;
}

@media screen and (max-width:920px) {

  nav {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu {
    width: 100%;
  }
  #cssmenu ul {
    width: 100%;
    display: none;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li {
    width: 100%;
        border-top: 1px solid rgba(251, 252, 252,0.5);
        background-color: #3B5921;
  }
  #cssmenu ul li:hover {
    background: #A4C74F;
  }

  #cssmenu > ul > li {
    /*float: none;*/
        padding: 25px;
        border-right: 0;
  }

  #cssmenu #head-mobile {
    display: block;
    padding: 23px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  .button {
    width: 55px;
    height: 46px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: -15px;
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 12399994;
  }
  .button:after {
    position: absolute;
    top: 22px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 8px;
    width: 28px;
    border-top: 2px solid #FBFCE8;
    border-bottom: 2px solid #FBFCE8;
    content: '';
  }
  .button:before {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    position: absolute;
    top: 16px;
    right: 20px;
    display: block;
    height: 2px;
    width: 28px;
    background: #FBFCE8;
    content: '';
  }
  .button.menu-opened:after {
    -webkit-transition: all .3s ease;
    -ms-transition: all .3s ease;
    transition: all .3s ease;
    top: 23px;
    border: 0;
    height: 2px;
    width: 27px;
    background: #fff;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
    transform: rotate(45deg);
  }
  .button.menu-opened:before {
    top: 23px;
    background: #fff;
    width: 27px;
    -webkit-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -moz-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -ms-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    -o-transform: rotate(-45deg);
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
  }
}
```

And here is the js

```
(function($) {
      $.fn.menumaker = function(options) {
        var cssmenu = $(this),
          settings = $.extend({
            format: "dropdown",
            sticky: false
          }, options);
        return this.each(function() {
          $(this).find(".button").on('click', function() {
            $(this).toggleClass('menu-opened');
            var mainmenu = $(this).next('ul');
            if (mainmenu.hasClass('open')) {
              mainmenu.slideToggle().removeClass('open');
            } else {
              mainmenu.slideToggle().addClass('open');
              if (settings.format === "dropdown") {
                mainmenu.find('ul').show();
              }
            }
          });
          cssmenu.find('li ul').parent().addClass('has-sub');
          multiTg = function() {
            cssmenu.find(".has-sub").prepend('<span class="submenu-button"></span>');
            cssmenu.find('.submenu-button').on('click', function() {
              $(this).toggleClass('submenu-opened');
              if ($(this).siblings('ul').hasClass('open')) {
                $(this).siblings('ul').removeClass('open').slideToggle();
              } else {
                $(this).siblings('ul').addClass('open').slideToggle();
              }
            });
          };
          if (settings.format === 'multitoggle') multiTg();
          else cssmenu.addClass('dropdown');
          if (settings.sticky === true) cssmenu.css('position', 'fixed');
          resizeFix = function() {
            var mediasize = 920;
            if ($(window).width() > mediasize) {
              cssmenu.find('ul').show();
            }
            if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
              cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
            }
          };
          resizeFix();
          return $(window).on('resize', resizeFix);
        });
      };
    })(jQuery);

    (function($) {
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $("#cssmenu").menumaker({
          format: "multitoggle"
        });
      });
   })(jQuery);
```

I also created a subdirectory with test files using the exact code from the pen and same thing happens on the phone - menu when open disappears on scroll.

Edited to add html for menu...

```
<nav id="cssmenu">
        <div id="head-mobile"></div>
        <div class="button"></div>
        <ul>
          <li class="first active"><a href="http://debrioconsulting.com/" title="Home">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="about" title="About">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="benefits" title="Benefits">Benefits</a></li>
          <li><a href="services" title="Services">Services</a></li>
          <li><a href="clients" title="Clients">Clients</a></li>
          <li class="last"><a href="contact" title="Contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
</nav>
```

Comment: Why did you choose to use emre. Not to be rude but creating a responsive menu could be done much easier by using bootstrap and the class `<nav class="nav navbar-collapse">`. So just out of curiosity. is there a special reason why you've chosen to use this path to create a responsive menu?

Comment: This appears to be an issue with the resize callback because it can also happen on desktop if you resize the window below the threshold width while it is open. Not entirely sure why you hiding when it is less than the media size but that definitely looks like why it is disappearing.

Comment: @Deathstorm is right but it looks like on scroll, the menu is being told to collapse - is this all the js relating to the menu/page?

Comment: could you provide some html ?

Comment: @Deathstorm - No special reason, found via search. I'll look into Bootstrap but curious to fix the existing issue.

Comment: @gbishop3 - Had a feeling it was something to do with the resize after searching for a solution, unfortunately I'm not well versed in js so not sure what needs to be altered.

Comment: My advice would be to check the [bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) annotation on how to use the dropown menu with bootstrap. Example of these you can find [here](https://bootsnipp.com/snippets/Gz9oE)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like commenting out the following 2 lines did the trick. Thanks @gbishop3 for pointing me in the right direction.

`//  if ($(window).width() <= mediasize) {
    //    cssmenu.find('ul').hide().removeClass('open');
    //  }`